# Box with text that takes up no space

Tags: spacing

On the cover sheet of an exam I'm writing I have a box for students to write their name. I'd also like to typeset the exact same box with some text written in place of the name.

Here is a MWE. I want the box on the left and the box on the right to be the same height (and width). I thought that `\smash` would make the “Your Name” box have no height, but it seems to make the framed box bigger.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[b]{8cm}
    \hfill\fbox{
        \begin{minipage}{.9\linewidth}
          Name:
          \vskip 1cm
          \vspace*{1mm}%
        \end{minipage}
  }\hfill\vspace{5ex}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{8cm}
    \hfill\fbox{
        \begin{minipage}{.9\linewidth}
          Name:
          \vskip 1cm
          \smash{\sffamily\Huge Your Name}
          \vspace*{1mm}%
        \end{minipage}
  }\hfill\vspace{5ex}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample code output]

I know how to do this in `tikz` but I feel like that's overkill. On the other hand, I've always been intimidated by spaces and skips and such. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4):

You can set the minipage's height explicitly:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}

\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[b][2cm][t]{8cm}
Name:
\end{minipage}}
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[b][2cm][t]{8cm}
Name:\vfill
\sffamily\Huge Your Name
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same thing with TeX primitives `:-)` (well, except `\fbox`)

```
\fbox{\vtop to2cm{\hsize8cm \parindent0pt Name:\vss}}
\fbox{\vtop to2cm{\hsize8cm \parindent0pt Name:\vss\sffamily\Huge Your Name}}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I forgot all about setting the vertical height of a minipage explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

Use a phantom in the box without the name.

You can also simplify the input, see the second realization.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry} % just to avoid overfull lines

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[b]{8cm}
  \fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{\dimeval{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}}
      Name:\par
      \vspace{1cm}
      \phantom{\sffamily\Huge\strut Your Name}
    \end{minipage}% <--- don't forget
  }
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{8cm}
  \fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{\dimeval{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}}
      Name:\par
      \vspace{1cm}
      \mbox{\sffamily\Huge\strut Your Name}
    \end{minipage}% <--- don't forget
  }
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\dimeval{8cm-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}}
    Name:\par
    \vspace{1cm}
    \phantom{\sffamily\Huge\strut Your Name}
  \end{minipage}% <--- don't forget
}
\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\dimeval{8cm-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}}
    Name:\par
    \vspace{1cm}
    \mbox{\sffamily\Huge\strut Your Name}
  \end{minipage}% <--- don't forget
}

\end{document}
```

No guess of the dimension of the inner box so that the whole thing is 8cm wide.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I know the nested minipages was redundant. I'm not sure where I got this code from, but I liked the way it looked so I never bothered to change it. I appreciate the streamlining.